# WPF validation stops working when changing tabs

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, data-binding

I have a WPF application where there is a `TabControl`, and within a certain tab there is a `TextBox` with a validation rule.

The validation rule works fine, the converter works fine, the binding is ok too.
But there is a very annoying bug (probably with WPF itself) that happens when I do this:

- Type an invalid text (the validation occurs, the textbox gets a red border)
- Change to another tab
- Return to the tab with the textbox.

The validation completely stops working until I type a **valid** text, then it starts working again.
Changing the text is not enough, it will only start working again if I enter a valid text.

How can I force a revalidation of the text when I enter the tab?

---

#### I already tried two solutions [listed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483419/force-validation-on-bound-controls-in-wpf/496871#496871), but they seem not to bring the red border:

- In an event `Selector.Selected` on the tab (checked that it's being called), add `txtName.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty).UpdateSource();`
- Use the `ValidatesOnTargetUpdated="True"` property in the validation rule

This is a brief description of the XAML, if needed:

```
<TabControl ...>
    <TabItem ... />
    <TabItem ...>
        ...
        <TextBox Name="txtName" ...>
            <TextBox.Text>
                <Binding Path="..." 
                         UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" 
                         Mode="OneWayToSource"
                         FallbackValue="5"
                         Converter="MyCustomConverterWorkingOk">

                     <Binding.ValidationRules>
                         <local:MyCustomValidationWorkingOk/>
                     </Binding.ValidationRules>
                </Binding> 
            </TextBox.Text>
        </TextBox>
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for this behavior is the way the `TabControl` displays its content: all tabs share the same `ContentPresenter`. When navigating between tabs, the old content is completely removed. This is also true for the `AdornerLayer`, on which the error template is rendered. Since the `AdornerLayer` is stateless and the `TabControl` doesn't monitor all the possible adorners, the old rendered error templates of the previous tab content can't be restored.

You have three good options:

1. don't allow the user to leave a tab unless the tab's data is in a valid state or
2. discard invalid data (which would also reset the related errors) when leaving the tab or
3. force the `AdornerLayer` to re-render when switching back to a `TabItem` which holds invalid data input.

The following example shows how you can force the `AdornerLayer` to render the adorner of all `TextBox` elements again as soon as the adorned element is visible:

```
<!-- Custom error template -->
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ValidationErrorTemplate">
  <StackPanel>

    <!-- Placeholder for the TextBox itself -->
    <AdornedElementPlaceholder />

    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ErrorContent}"
               Foreground="Red" />
  </StackPanel>
</ControlTemplate>

<!-- Style to trigger the rendering of the AdornerLayer by setting the error template -->
<Style TargetType="TextBox">
  <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate"
          Value="{x:Null}" />
  <Style.Triggers>
    <MultiTrigger>
      <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
        <Condition Property="Validation.HasError"
                   Value="True" />
        <Condition Property="IsVisible"
                   Value="True" />
      </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
      <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate"
              Value="{StaticResource ValidationErrorTemplate}" />
    </MultiTrigger>
  </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Give each TabItem its own AdornerLayer (via the AdornerDecorator element) as shown below. The elements in the adorner layer will be maintained across tab switches.

```
<TabItem Header="Tab 1">
    <AdornerDecorator>
        <Grid Background="WhiteSmoke">
            <TextBlock Text="Hello from #1" />
        </Grid>
    </AdornerDecorator>
</TabItem>

<TabItem Header="Tab 2">
    <AdornerDecorator>
        <Grid Background="WhiteSmoke">
            <TextBlock Text="Hello from #2" />
        </Grid>
    </AdornerDecorator>
</TabItem>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but try this:

```
string text = txtName.Text;
txtName.Text = null;
txtName.Text = text;
```